# Setting environment variables at the end of a command?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, zsh

In order to set an env var inline one simply runs:

`ENV_VAR=value command --args`

Is there a way to set the env var at the end of the command?

Comment: How would you know it will not an argument? What would you do if you would want to pass `ENV_VAR=value` _string_ as an argument to the command?

Comment: Aside from the fact that there is no syntax provided for what you want, what effect would you expect? With `VAR=VALUE command`, you set `VAR` in the environment of _command_, and after command is finished, the variable is gone. If the environment could be modified just before the command is finished, it would not have any visible effect whatever.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Quoting from bash documentation:

A simple command is a sequence of optional variable assignments followed by blank-separated words and redirections, and terminated by a control operator.

It is the same for zsh.